# How to set the background color of a div in ionic 2?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

I want to set the background-color of a div.For eg: gray color in first div,blue color in second div.I'm displaying data in div tag using ngFor .How can i set different background-colors for particular div. Please advise.

```
<div style="background-color: #DFE0E2;border:solid pink;float:left;width:30%;margin-left:20px;" *ngFor="let list of dataa">
      <img src="assets/imgs/user.png" style="padding-left:70px;">
      <footer style="background-color: #ffffff;padding:5px;margin:0px;">
        <p style="margin:5px;font-size:18px;">{{list.name}}
          <ion-icon ios="ios-create" md="md-create" (click)="user(list)"></ion-icon>
        </p>
        <p style="margin:5px;color:#808B96">{{list.tagline}}</p>
      </footer>
    </div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the below code it uses ngclass for providing different class as per needed.

```
  In your .ts File:

  <ion-item *ngFor="let item of items;let i = index;">
  <div [ngClass]="i%2 === 0 ? 'gray' : 'white'"></div>
  </ion-item>

  In .css file:
  .gray{
   background-color: #EBE5D9;
  }
  .white{
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
  }
```

Comment: Now i want to change gray color in first div, blue in second div, pink in third div , #EBE5D9 in fourth div and #FFFFFF in fifth div.

Comment: for that u had to create a function send 0,1,2,3... values to that function and in .ts file assign the hexcolour values.

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this. By using `ngClass`.

**Code.html**

```
<ul *ngFor="let person of people">
  <li [ngStyle]="{'font-size.px':24}"
      [style.color]="getColor(person.country)">
    {{ person.name }} ({{ person.country }})
  </li>
</ul>
```

**Code.ts**

```
     getColor(country) {
    switch (country) {
      case 'UK':
        return 'green';
      case 'USA':
        return 'blue';
      case 'HK':
        return 'red';
    }
  }
```

Refer to this [link](https://codecraft.tv/courses/angular/built-in-directives/ngstyle-and-ngclass/) for more understanding.

Answer (score 0):

with odd,event color in div

```
<div [style.background-color]="arrayColor[i%2]" style="border:solid pink;float:left;width:30%;margin-left:20px;" *ngFor="let list of dataa; let i = index">
      <img src="assets/imgs/user.png" style="padding-left:70px;">
      <footer style="background-color: #ffffff;padding:5px;margin:0px;">
        <p style="margin:5px;font-size:18px;">{{list.name}}
          <ion-icon ios="ios-create" md="md-create" (click)="user(list)"></ion-icon>
        </p>
        <p style="margin:5px;color:#808B96">{{list.tagline}}</p>
      </footer>
    </div>
```

arrayColor in .ts

```
arrayColor = {
0: '#CCCCCC',
1: '#DFE0E2'
}
```

Comment: I used this code but it gives me error 'Cannot read property '0' of undefined'

Comment: do you define arrayColor variable in component?